# What's called when copying a property

Tags: objective-c, properties

When we have property with memory identifier `copy`, what class method will be called by system to copy my object?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean system calls some method under it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Objective-C property marked as `copy` will make use of the `copy` method from the `NSObject` class. Essentially, the auto-synthesized setter method will look something like this:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {
    _name = [name copy];
}
```

There's more to it than that (key-value observing, etc.) but what I show covers your question.

If the property is for your own custom class, be sure your class conforms to `NSCopying` and properly implements the `copyWithZone:` method.

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that your property is of some class that adopts NSCopying, and `copy` (actually `copyWithZone:`) will be called on it.

So, studying what you need in order to conform to NSCopying will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: What if my class do not conforms to NSCopying?

Comment: Then you will crash.